# Rigorous proof of this limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I have shown that the function $$f(x):=\int_{[-\pi,\pi]^n} \frac{e^{-i\langle k,x \rangle}}{1-\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \cos(k_i)}dk$$

exists everywhere for $n \ge 3$.

Now, I want to show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) \|x\|^{n-2}=c$ for some non-zero constant $c.$ Here $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}$ means that $x_1,\ldots,x_n \rightarrow \infty.$

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter sorry, I forgot the condition $n \ge 3$.

Comment: Doesn't $f(x)\to 0$ by the RL Lemma?

Comment: @zhw yes, but the question is what we know about the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)||x||^{2-n}$

Comment: I know. But $|x|^{2-n} \to 0$ too.

Comment: @zhw I am really sorry, I messed this up. You are right, it has to be $|x|^{n-2}.$

Comment: @Zimkovic : Notice the conspicuous visual difference between $||a|| ||b||$ and $\|a\|\|b\|$.  The former is coded as ||a|| ||b|| and the latter as \|a\|\|b\|.  The latter is standard usage for a reason. I edited the question accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$